# How to detect if insert transactions in oracle db are slow?

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-11g

At work, I have an Oracle DB (11g) in which I want to detect if there's slow performance while inserting data.
Here's the situation:

Some production devices send data results from tests to Server A, this server is a important server and it replicates the info to server B, which is the one that processes the data (files) to then insert it into the database with the problem, the database is in another server (Server C).

Now, the problem that I'm facing is that the data in server B is getting stuck there, a queue starts to form and it keeps growing and growing. Apparently the insertion is to slow, to give you an idea, in the Server A (which inserts data in a DB also in server A) the time to insert a single set of data goes from 133 ms to (very rarely) 2300 ms; while in server B it goes from 171 to 11900 (most likely to be above 2 seconds).

As you can see there're a lot of factors here, the capacity between Server A and Server B are also different, Server A has 96 GB of memory and server B has 32; Server A 24 CPU's, GenuineIntel, CPU MHz 1596; and Server B 16 CPU's, AutenticAMD, CPU MHz 3200.
I think it could be a problem of capacity in Server B; but I'd like to rule out a problem in the database; that's why I would like to find out if the insertion of data in the DB is really slow, because when my applications connect to it to read data, it does really okay, it's not slow.
Also, server B is the only one that inserts data into the DB in server C. I have no access to the insides of the applications that processes the data in Server B, and unfortunately there's almost not documentation to read.
Now, I'm not DBA, but I'd like to find a way to spy on the inserts and find out how long are they taking to finish.
Anybody know how I could achieve this?

Thank you!!